# VB function get() from SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

In excel, I want to write a function like following:

```
Function GetDCF(vari As String)

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

Dim strConn As String
Dim sql As String

strConn = "PROVIDER=xxxx;DATA SOURCE=xxxxx;INITIAL CATALOG=Research;xxxxx SECURITY=sspi;"
cn.Open strConn
sql = "select '" & vari & " from TBLmontecarlodcf where COMPANY = '" & Range("A2").Value & "' "
rs.Open sql, cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
GetDCF = rs!vari
cn.Close

Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing

End Function
```

For the line  `GetDCF = rs!vari`, I know the code is incorrect, but I don't know how to fix it?
Should it be something like `GetDCF = rs!'" & vari & "`?

Basically, I'm not sure how to pass the value from the SQL query to my VBA function.

Thanks for advice!

Comment: use `GetDCF = rs.Fields(vari)`

Comment: hmm, I tried your code, but it seems doesn't work? i know i missed ' in my select query in above post, but I had fixed in my vb code. Could that be GetDCF = rs!Fields(vari)?

Comment: @simoco line should work.  Try hard coding the value and testing.  Then `Trim()` it to make sure there are no spaces.

Comment: i have a field called GITR, it works with sql = "select GITR  from TBLmontecarlodcf where COMPANY = '" & Range("A2").Value & "' "

rs.Open sql, cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

GetDCF = rs!GITR, but when I use GetDCF = rs.fields("vari"), it doesn't work?

Comment: OK, looks like GetDCF = rs.Fields(vari) is fine, but there is sth wrong with sql = "select '" & vari & " from... Can I write in that way?

Comment: OK, I got, it, i simply need to write select * from...